# Spring + Thymeleaf not able to populate String on render

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a testt.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.thymeleaf.org ">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Advanced Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#" th:action="@{getClasses}" method="GET">
<br />
<br />
<p style="margin-left: 35px">Submit fully classified package names</p>
        Class Name: <input type="text" name="class_name" size="90px"></input> 
        <input type="text" name="classes" size="90px" th:field="${foo}"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" ></input> <br />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And have the following code in the controller method:

```
model.addAttribute("foo", "foo");
                return "testt";
```

Why "foo" is not populating in the html? If instead of String i add an object and try to get its variable it works fine.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to submit the form and capture the submitted value in the controller, or are you trying to pre-populate the form with the value set in the controller method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think if you want use it like this you should use `th:value` instead of `th:field`

Answer (score 0):

You need this `th:field=__${foo}__`,

have a look at the doc here:http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html